# StanfordCoreNLP as thread

Tags: java, stanford-nlp

i'm a 4th Software engineer student and my final project is about converting user stories .
I'm using "Stanford Core NLP" ; My props list is "tokenize, ssplit, pos, lemma, ner, parse" and the ner prop make it very slow.

I write my code in java, and i would like to ask if there is some way to use with the class who implements the stanford pipeline as a thread. 
Can this benefit me the running time?
For each user story I load the class that implement the StanfordNLP from the beginning.
How do I make it one-time loaded?

Comment: An aside, but you can speed up NER by setting the property: `props.setProperty("ner.applyFineGrained", "false")`

Answer (score 0):

You should just build the pipeline once and then have the pipeline process each story.  If you post some of your sample code I can help you improve it.  You can also run the pipeline in multi-thread mode and have multiple cores processing at once.

Answer (score 0):

this is the class that implement the StanfordNLP - "SentimentAnalyzer".
I want to use with this class few times for differents algorithems.
Where should I call this class so that it will not hurt me when I'm running the project?

public class SentimentAnalyzer {

```
private StanfordCoreNLP pipeline;


//private Hashtable<String, ArrayList<String>> POS_TaggingArray; // k, v


public void initializeCoreNLP() {


    Properties props = new Properties();
    props.put("annotators", "tokenize, ssplit, pos, lemma, ner, parse");
    pipeline = new StanfordCoreNLP(props);

}

public void getSentiment(String text) {

    int index = 0;

    Annotation annotation= new Annotation(text);
    pipeline.annotate(annotation);

    Hashtable<String, ArrayList<String>> POS_array = new Hashtable<String, ArrayList<String>>();
    List<String> sentances_list=new ArrayList<>(  );
    List<Tree> constituencyParse = new ArrayList<>(  );
    List<String> W_lemmas= new ArrayList<>(  );
    String[] ner;

    ner = new String[text.length()];

    List<CoreMap> sentences = annotation.get( CoreAnnotations.SentencesAnnotation.class ); //divide to sentences

    for (CoreMap sentence : sentences) {
        sentances_list.add( sentence.toString() );
        constituencyParse.add( sentence.get(TreeCoreAnnotations.TreeAnnotation.class) )  ;
        for (CoreLabel token : sentence.get( CoreAnnotations.TokensAnnotation.class )) {
            String word = token.get( CoreAnnotations.TextAnnotation.class );//get the word
            String pos = token.get( CoreAnnotations.PartOfSpeechAnnotation.class );//get part of sentance

            String key = String.valueOf( POS_array.get(pos) );
            if(key.equals( "null" )) {
                POS_array.put(pos, new ArrayList<String>());
                POS_array.get(pos).add(word);
            } else{

                POS_array.get(pos).add(word);

            }
            if(pos.equals( "NN" ) || pos.equals( "NNS" ) || pos.equals( "NNP" ) || pos.equals(  "NNSP" )){   //for w list
                W_lemmas.add( token.get(CoreAnnotations.LemmaAnnotation.class) );
                String role = token.get( CoreAnnotations.NamedEntityTagAnnotation.class );
                if (!(role==null)) {
                    ner[index]=role;
                }
                else {
                    ner[index]="empty";
                }
            }
            index+=1;
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: What main() method are you calling ?  Make sure to only call initializeCoreNLP once.